# Using jQuery Validate's invalidHandler event

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, jquery-plugins, jquery-validate

I need to add a class to div that is wrapped around the select element upon validation.

```
$("#Form").validate({
    invalidHandler: function (form, validator) {
        $("[id$='_DropDownList']").each(function () {
            // How do I figure out if $(this) is valid or invalid?
            // Add the class below if invalid.
            $(this).parent().addClass("error");
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [`.valid()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/valid) method, like this:

```
$("#Form").validate({
    invalidHandler: function (form, validator) {
        $("[id$='_DropDownList']").each(function () {
            if(!$(this).valid())
              $(this).parent().addClass("error");
        });
    }
});
```

However, the [`highlight` and `unhightlight` options](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions) are specifically for this:

```
$("#Form").validate({
  highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
    $(element).parent().removeClass(validClass).addClass(errorClass);
  },
  unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
    $(element).parent().removeClass(errorClass).addClass(validClass);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this code is correct:

```
$(this).parent().addClass("error");
```

Maybe your issue is with the code surrounding it... Try moving your addClass line outside the function it is in to see if it work there.

Answer (score 0):

`invalidHandler` is only called when the form is submitted and not valid. I believe adding your code under that function alone is enough.