# Unable to remove class on unobtrusive validation fail

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, unobtrusive-validation

I am wondering if anyone here can help me work out why I am unable to remove a class from a button when validation fails.

On our login page when someone clicks the `Login` button I am adding a class to give it a loading animation. The problem is that I am unable to remove this when the validation fails.

So for example if someone just clicks `Login` and the username and password fields are both empty it will pop up the error messages as expected, but i need to remove the loading animation and everything I have tried doesn't seem to work.

Here is my HTML:

```
  using (Html.BeginForm(ControllersAndActions.UsersController.LogIn, ControllersAndActions.UsersController.Name, FormMethod.Post, new {id="LoginForm"}))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <div class="loginArea">

            <div class="welcomeMessage">@Html.Translate(AccountsToken.AccessMessage)</div>

            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Username, new {placeholder = AccountsToken.Username.Translate()}) 
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Password, new {placeholder = AccountsToken.Password.Translate(), type = "password"})
            <div class="loginError">
                @Html.ValidationSummary()
            </div>
            <div class="loginLostPassword">
                <a class="loginLostPasswordLink" href="@Url.Action(ControllersAndActions.UsersController.LostPassword, ControllersAndActions.UsersController.Name)">@Html.Translate(AccountsToken.ForgottenPasswordQM)</a>
            </div>
            <div class="loginLoginBut"><button type=submit class="loginButton butLogin">@Html.Translate(AccountsToken.LogIn)</button></div>
            <div class="loginRememberMe"><label class="rememberMeLabel">@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.RememberMe) @Html.Translate(AccountsToken.StoreAsACookieQM)</label></div>
        </div>

        if (Html.RegistrationsAllowed() != SiteRegistrationAllowed.DenySiteRegistration)
        {
            <div class="registrationArea">
                <div class="registrationMessage">@Html.DisplayTextPanel("[LoginRegistrationMessage]", IsAdmin ? "[Click edit to change this text]" : null)</div>
                <div class="registrationBut"><a class="loginButton butRegister" href="@Url.Action(ControllersAndActions.UsersController.Registration, ControllersAndActions.UsersController.Name)">@Html.Translate(AccountsToken.Register)</a></div>

            </div>
        }
    }
```

The script I have currently is as follows:

```
 <script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.validator.setDefaults({
        invalidHandler: function (form, validator) {
            $(".butLogin").removeClass("butLoading");
        }
    });
});
$(function() {
    $(".butLogin").on("click", function () {
        $(this).addClass("butLoading");
    });

});
```

I have tried the solutions from the following questions with no joy:

[How to set an invalidHandler for all forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14823860/how-to-set-an-invalidhandler-for-all-forms)

[Using jQuery Validate's invalidHandler event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616947/using-jquery-validates-invalidhandler-event)

[invalidHandler on next button with jQuery validation plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9839977/invalidhandler-on-next-button-with-jquery-validation-plugin)

I wasted a whole afternoon yesterday trying to get this working, so I would really appreciate any help or suggestions that people have here. Hopefully I am not just being stupid, as I am pretty sure that this should be relatively simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this,

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {
    $(".butLogin").on("click", function () {
            $(this).addClass("butLoading");
            var validation = $("#LoginForm");
            if (!validation.valid()) {
            $(this).removeClass("butLoading"); 
            return false;
            }
    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks will give it a go shortly

Comment: That works a charm, thankyou so much. I am sure i tried something similar yesterday to no avail.